# phpdotenv download many packages

Tags: php, composer-php, phpdotenv

I wanna to use **phpdotenv** in my project. I read it installation guide and run `composer require vlucas/phpdotenv` inside my project. Now it downloads many other packages except vlucas/phpdotenv in a folder named **vendor** as below.

[image]

Do I need to maintain all of them or *vlucas/phpdotenv* is enough. If yes how can I merge these folders with other vendors folder while there is an *autoload.php* which is need to be included.

Comment: Why are there **multiple** vendor folders? There should be exactly one for your application

Comment: I used a project template which contains a folder named `vendors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All packages that are being installed using composer are kept under directory named as `vendor`. So you will see all installed packages over here.

Now there is a feature that you require in your project(`Loading environment variables from .env`) and for that you're using another package(`vlucas/phpdotenv`) as your project dependency.

In the same manner `vlucas/phpdotenv` package is also developed by another developer who relies on multiple packages for his project to work smoothly just like yours. So all packages which were used in this package as dependency will also be installed in your `vendor` folder.

Now ***how these are installed***:
Check `composer.json` file at root of your project. It contains keys like `require` and `require-dev`, data inside these attributes tells composer to install packages for your project.

In the same way when you'll look `composer.json` of `vlucas/phpdotenv` project, you'll see a list of all of your mentioned packages inside that. Composer auto detects them and install them, so you don't have to manually installed them to make vlucas work in your project.

[composer.json](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/master/composer.json) file of `vlucas/phpdotenv`.

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3 || ^8.0",
        "ext-pcre": "*",
        "graham-campbell/result-type": "^1.0.1",
        "phpoption/phpoption": "^1.7.4",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "^1.17",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.17",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "^1.17"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. SO to confirm, Do I need all of them?

Comment: Yes, you will be needing all of them.